# Apache Isis: Java Type mapping failed

Tags: java, datanucleus, isis

I have one problem with the open source estatio (that is built based on apache isis)

I've export data base schema first in DDL file. After that I have imported the DDL file in PostgresSQL 9.5. The application can be started. And some of fixture can be executed. The problem I have in "Estatio Demo Fixture". The application seems to import few fixtures until the application try to import org.estatio.fixture.financial.BankAccountForAcmeNl.
Following exception occurs:

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException
Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1@4c421e92 on component [IndicatingAjaxButton [Component id = okButton]] threw an exception
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor#respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack#execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter#doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1#call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject#execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter#doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve#invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve#invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase#invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve#invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve#invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve#invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve#invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor#service(Http11Processor.java:783)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight#process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler#process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor#doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase#run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable#run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread#run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor#respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack#execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter#doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1#call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject#execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter#doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve#invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve#invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase#invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve#invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve#invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve#invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve#invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor#service(Http11Processor.java:783)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight#process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler#process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor#doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase#run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable#run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread#run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "nextvalIncodeCommunications.CommunicationChannel_id_seq::regclass"
java.lang.NumberFormatException#forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Long#parseLong(Long.java:589)
java.lang.Long#valueOf(Long.java:803)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.datastore.BigIntRDBMSMapping#setObject(BigIntRDBMSMapping.java:187)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.DatastoreIdMapping#setObject(DatastoreIdMapping.java:53)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping#setObjectAsNull(PersistableMapping.java:346)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping#setObject(PersistableMapping.java:317)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping#setObject(PersistableMapping.java:300)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatementHelper#applyParametersToStatement(SQLStatementHelper.java:228)
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery#performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:609)
org.datanucleus.store.query.Query#executeQuery(Query.java:1855)
org.datanucleus.store.query.Query#executeWithMap(Query.java:1762)
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery#executeWithMap(JDOQuery.java:346)
org.apache.isis.objectstore.jdo.datanucleus.persistence.queries.PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor#getResults(PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor.java:117)
org.apache.isis.objectstore.jdo.datanucleus.persistence.queries.PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor#process(PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor.java:57)
org.apache.isis.objectstore.jdo.datanucleus.persistence.queries.PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor#process(PersistenceQueryFindUsingApplibQueryProcessor.java:41)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession#processPersistenceQuery(PersistenceSession.java:606)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession#access$000(PersistenceSession.java:147)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession$1#execute(PersistenceSession.java:567)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession$1#execute(PersistenceSession.java:564)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager#executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:188)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager#executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:178)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession#findInstancesInTransaction(PersistenceSession.java:563)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.persistence.PersistenceSession#firstMatchingQuery(PersistenceSession.java:535)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.services.persistsession.PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault#firstMatchingQuery(PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault.java:176)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.services.container.DomainObjectContainerDefault#firstMatch(DomainObjectContainerDefault.java:534)
org.incode.module.communications.dom.impl.commchannel.CommunicationChannelOwnerLinkRepository#findByCommunicationChannel(CommunicationChannelOwnerLinkRepository.java:65)
org.incode.module.communications.dom.impl.commchannel.CommunicationChannel#getOwnerLink(CommunicationChannel.java:253)
org.incode.module.communications.dom.impl.commchannel.CommunicationChannel#removeOwnerLink(CommunicationChannel.java:246)
org.incode.module.communications.dom.impl.commchannel.CommunicationChannel#setOwner(CommunicationChannel.java:241)
org.incode.module.communications.dom.impl.commchannel.CommunicationChannelRepository#newPostal(CommunicationChannelRepository.java:73)
org.estatio.fixture.party.OrganisationAbstract#createCommunicationChannels(OrganisationAbstract.java:90)
org.estatio.fixture.party.OrganisationAbstract#createOrganisation(OrganisationAbstract.java:69)
org.estatio.fixture.party.OrganisationForAcmeNl#execute(OrganisationForAcmeNl.java:30)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildIfNotAlready(FixtureScript.java:598)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildT(FixtureScript.java:576)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildT(FixtureScript.java:544)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChild(FixtureScript.java:532)
org.estatio.fixture.financial.BankAccountForAcmeNl#execute(BankAccountForAcmeNl.java:42)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildIfNotAlready(FixtureScript.java:598)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildT(FixtureScript.java:576)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildT(FixtureScript.java:544)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChild(FixtureScript.java:532)
org.estatio.fixturescripts.EstatioDemoFixture#execute(EstatioDemoFixture.java:72)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#executeChildIfNotAlready(FixtureScript.java:598)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript$ExecutionContext#access$200(FixtureScript.java:253)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScript#run(FixtureScript.java:828)
org.apache.isis.applib.fixturescripts.FixtureScripts#runFixtureScript(FixtureScripts.java:391)
org.apache.isis.applib.services.fixturespec.FixtureScriptsDefault#runFixtureScript(FixtureScriptsDefault.java:108)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract#invokeMethodElseFromCache(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:407)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$2#execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:261)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$2#execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:222)
org.apache.isis.applib.services.iactn.Interaction#executeInternal(Interaction.java:173)
org.apache.isis.applib.services.iactn.Interaction#execute(Interaction.java:143)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract#doInvoke(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:310)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract$1#execute(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:164)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager#executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:142)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager#executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:132)
org.apache.isis.core.runtime.services.persistsession.PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault#executeWithinTransaction(PersistenceSessionServiceInternalDefault.java:181)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.facets.actions.action.invocation.ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract#invoke(ActionInvocationFacetForDomainEventAbstract.java:160)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault#executeInternal(ObjectActionDefault.java:400)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault#execute(ObjectActionDefault.java:389)
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.specimpl.ObjectActionDefault#executeWithRuleChecking(ObjectActionDefault.java:370)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel#executeAction(ActionModel.java:491)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel#load(ActionModel.java:469)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel#load(ActionModel.java:81)
org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel#getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:135)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.model.models.ActionModel#execute(ActionModel.java:597)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.components.actions.ActionFormExecutorStrategy#obtainResultAdapter(ActionFormExecutorStrategy.java:72)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.FormExecutorDefault#obtainResultAdapter(FormExecutorDefault.java:498)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.FormExecutorDefault#executeAndProcessResults(FormExecutorDefault.java:129)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.PromptFormAbstract#onOkSubmittedOf(PromptFormAbstract.java:228)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.PromptFormAbstract#access$000(PromptFormAbstract.java:60)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.PromptFormAbstract$1#onSubmit(PromptFormAbstract.java:122)
org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1#onSubmit(AjaxButton.java:113)
org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter#onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form#delegateSubmit(Form.java:1307)
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form#process(Form.java:976)
org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.ui.panels.FormAbstract#process(FormAbstract.java:77)
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form#onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior#onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior#respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior#onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke(Method.java:498)
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface#invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler#respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor#respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack#execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter#doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter#doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1#call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable#call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject#execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter#doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter#doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve#invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve#invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase#invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve#invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve#invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve#invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve#invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor#service(Http11Processor.java:783)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight#process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler#process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor#doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase#run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable#run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread#run(Thread.java:745)
```

The id of CommunicationChanel is described like following in DB: "id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"IncodeCommunications"."CommunicationChannel_id_seq"'::regclass)"

The Id of this table is automatically created for each insert statement. In this case that is not an insert statement but a find statement without reference Id. I mean it looks up in CommunicationChanelOwnerLink, if there is any row with id is blank.

```
public void setObject(PreparedStatement ps, int param, Object value)
{
    try
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            if (column != null && column.isDefaultable() && column.getDefaultValue() != null && !StringUtils.isWhitespace(column.getDefaultValue().toString()))
            {
                ps.setLong(param, Long.valueOf(column.getDefaultValue().toString().trim()).longValue());
            }
            else
```

this block code of **BigIntRDBMSMapping** says that, if the value is null (that is exactly in this case) then it will try to parse default value that was initialized by datanucleus before. In this case, default value = "nextvalIncodeCommunications.CommunicationChannel_id_seq::regclass". This value can not be convert to Long value.

Any idea what is exactly happen here?
Thanks.

Comment: This issue can be related with https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/issues/80

Comment: and related also with https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/issues/83

Comment: you havent defined what you're doing at the time of that exception. executing a query? if so what query? if those issues are related then why not use what the second one does and set datanucleus.rdbms.useColumnDefaultWhenNull to false?

Comment: The issue I had above is not related to two commits also. That is the place where datanucleus-rdbms is not well support. I summarize the whole situation: I created a search query on table "IncodeCommunications"."CommunicationChannel" with criteria: CommunicationChanel.id is null. Also I search for all CommunicationChanel where id is null. During processing preprared statement, datanucleus find out that "id" of table has default value (using sequence) and the framework immediately parse "default value" to target type ( in this case is long). But in this case default value is a sql statement

Comment: there are two issues: default value should be parsed and applied for INSERT (automatically increment primary key) but not for SELECT; default  value should be parsed correctly. That is a issue with datanucleus-rdbms, not with Apache isis

Comment: @BillyFrost your purposed property can not help, as I said above, that is not an INSERT statement, that was a SELECT

Comment: so its is NOT related to those links then ...

Comment: @BillyFrost no that is not. That was my thought but that was not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use case: see my comment [Apache Isis: Java Type mapping failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661270/apache-isis-java-type-mapping-failed#comment78710633_45661270)

root cause: see my comment [Apache Isis: Java Type mapping failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661270/apache-isis-java-type-mapping-failed#comment78710713_45661270)

solution: no official solution exists. I've talked with Andy Jefferson from datanucleus team. But no useful answer. At the end I've patched the library by my self and wait for appropriate fix

Comment: I saw a conversation on DataNucleus Gitter and it seems to request you to provide a fix (since you are presumably the only person who has that issue). Keeping your "fix" (and definition of your problem) to yourself is firstly NOT in the spirit of open source, and secondly not going to help anyone else if they ever have that problem. Good luck with that

Comment: @NeilStockton: actually I don't have a fix for this. as the discussion in Gitter, I'm not really sure about how to fix this. Andy said that a feature to parse default value is missing for datanucleus. But I think my situation is not that case. I don't have issue with insert, but with select, and I still think that is a bug, not the feature that Andy talking about. What I can do is to open issue in github for this issue and provide a fix for this if it is confirmed an issue. And I think that the fix should be occurs in different classes, not only one